# How to put 3 ArcGIS feature classes together with SQL 2012 geometry with a view?

Tags: arcgis-server, sql, geometry

I made a pretty table view with the below sql but at the end I added the shape field and I got an error I cannot union like that with geometry?

```
SELECT        Type, HearingDate, SiteID AS 'ITEM'
FROM            myfirstfeatureclasshere
UNION
SELECT        'Zoning Board of Appeals' AS Type, HearingDate, CaseNo AS 'ITEM'
FROM            mysecondfeatureclasshere
UNION
SELECT        Type, HearingDate, ITEM
FROM            mythirdfeatureclasshere
```

Answer (score 2):

you missed the quotes around ITEM on your last union:

```
SELECT        Type, HearingDate, SiteID AS 'ITEM'
FROM            myfirstfeatureclasshere
UNION
SELECT        'Zoning Board of Appeals' AS Type, HearingDate, CaseNo AS 'ITEM'
FROM            mysecondfeatureclasshere
UNION
SELECT        Type, HearingDate, 'ITEM'
FROM            mythirdfeatureclasshere
```